# a single word for someone who does a routine but important job

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

someone who performs a job on daily basis, but his job is important and vital for normal procession. like the one who checks the cards at a casino before it is played, one who test drives the bike that is gonna be used in MotoGP, the one responsible to bring the tyres in time for Ferrari so that the assembly line is not slowed down and similar types.

an assistant doesn't fit the job and a worker is too common. I can recall it being another word, that is less than 6 letters. I can't find it on internet.

Comment: S/he has a *crucial* role/position/job. But that's an adjective...hmmm... *indispensable*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to such indispensable workers as *cogs* in a machine, bureaucracy, or company. The role of a cog may be minor or even looked down upon but nevertheless "important and vital for normal" operations.

Answer (score 1):

**[wallah](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wallah)**

> 1. One employed in a particular occupation or activity: *a kitchen wallah; rickshaw wallahs.*
> 2. An important person in a particular field or organization: *"the Ritz, a favorite haunt of Republican wallahs" (John Robinson).*

Answer (score 0):

[Aide](http://thesaurus.com/browse/aide) or *crew* comes to mind

Less important people are

- flunky
- gofer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe **Linchpin** or **Lynchpin**? More than six letters but...

See definition #2 at [Oxford Dictionaries Linchpin](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/linchpin)

> A person or thing vital to an enterprise or organization

Comment: I think linchpins usually have more significant roles than the examples in the question. Those jobs may be important, but they're not "vital".

Answer (score 0):

Consider the terms:

- [**cornerstone**](http://magazine.uc.edu/famousalumni/names/BarryBishop.html)
- [**pillar**](http://www.rolandberger.com/expertise/experts/expert_profile/rbsc-exp-Dr_Martin_Tonko.html)

Comment: As with Frank's answer "linchpin", these terms are usually used for a more central part of the organization.